# How to read Chrome/Firefox Pop up actions Leave/Stay when we the leave the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
When ever u made some change to page and try to leave chrome/firefox throws a alert.  Data you entered may not be saved with (Leave or Stay) buttons.
How i can do certain action when user clicks leaves or stay.
```

To which event i need to listen to to make actions when we click leave or stay?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no window close event.You can use `onbeforeunload` to prevent asking for simple confirmation etc.

That is what is done internally by website developers on their page. But you can't read that answer from an user script. It is simply the website developers implementation.You can't read user's response given to website developers `confirm` question by user from an application.

**Those popups are implemented by the corresponding websites not browser.**

### Solution

Modern browsers now consider displaying a custom message to be a security hazard and it is removed therefore. Browsers now only display generic messages. So we can simply do this:-

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return false;
};
window.onbeforeunload = null; // this will not show any popup.
```

So just remove everything fron `onbeforeunload` and return false and make it null. This will solve your problem.

Note: You can't show custom message or do anything significant using `onbeforeunload`. That is the answer to your question originally asked.

Comment: Still i am seeing the browser confirmation.

Comment: @user1844634.: Did you follow what I said? Returning false etc..check my answer once. Return false